# Showing an inequality with the subgaussian and Lp norm, and also showing that $\|X\|_2$ is subgaussian.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, lp-spaces, expected-value

I am trying to show two things:

Firstly:

Suppose $X$ is a sub gaussian random variable, then we have:
$$\|X\|_{L^p}:=\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]^{\frac{1}{p}}\le{C\|X\|_{\psi^2}\sqrt{p}},\space{}C>0$$

I don't really know where to even begin with this, I looked at the definition of the expectation here:
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^\infty{\mathbb{P}(X>t)}dt$$
But couldn't get anywhere.

And Secondly:

If $X=(X_1,...,X_N)$ is a random vector with independent subgaussian co-ordinates, are $\|X\|_2$ and $\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n}$ subgaussian?